# Which pod should we use instead of GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

I am using pod GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK in my application. I see that it is deprecated now. Which one is replacement for that with all the existing functions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> Open the Podfile created for your application and add the following:

```
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/

Answer (score 0):

Having wasted an inordinate amount of time keeping Google Analytics running cleanly in an existing app, I finally found this statement by Google:

"Note: The Firebase SDK is the recommended method to track iOS apps"

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift